# Deploying Astro with GitHub Pages - No astro.config.mjs

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, astrojs

So I am new to CI/CD and am trying to deploy a new portfolio website to GitHub pages using a more modern workflow mostly just to learn. The workflow is encountering an error that debug and log files don't seem to help with too much (probably me misunderstanding).

I followed tutorials from GitHub and generated a repo and workflow using [this](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/github/) and [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions). I used the template that GitHub provides for Astro and after installing npm I was able to get the basic workflow to run through a few steps without error when committing changes. Now I am encountering an error that seems to point to me not having an "astro.config.mjs" file. I was under the impression GitHub would generate all needed files apart from the package-lock.json npm generated for me. My website does not have a custom domain so my assumption is that I need to delete the "base:" directory field in the "astro.config.mjs" as indicated [here](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/github/) but I do not have that file in any of my directories, just the deploy.yml and package-lock.json file. I figure I am missing something due to lack of experience in CI/CD. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi rickandm00rty! Could you list all the files in the base of your repo? If possible, sharing a link to the repo on GitHub would be helpful.

Comment: @swithinbank I think I was able to figure out my issue just now. The directions were not entirely streamlined on GitHub's website. I was under the impression the 'astro.config.mjs' would be generated when GitHub generated the Astro template project for me. Little did I know I needed to install Astro itself locally using npm which then created that file for me. Long story short I was able to work in reverse and create an Astro project locally first and then initialize a repo and add it to GitHub. Now my repo contains the necessary files including the 'package-lock.json' and 'astro.config.mjs'